Algolia on Adobe Commerce (Magento 2) High Volume of Product Reindexes
We have Algolia installed on a multi store instance but only enabled for a low traffic store whilst we test it's success and stability.
The indexing queue builds up and up throughout the day and is never cleared despite the algolia_queue_runner being able to handle 50 jobs at a time, every 5 minutes.
The jobs in the indexing queue just keep stacking up and up. Product data is changed on a fortnightly basis via imports and sales are relatively low for the store Algolia is enabled for.
We are seeing 'product reindexes' being applied for single productIds or a range of productIDs.
